# Database design for different groups access and display results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make different roles access to admin dashboard. For now they are `superadmin` and `admin`.. later I will add 2 more but for now are just this two. For now `superadmin` has all permissions include to create new admins. Admin will have permission to create normal users later but for now differences between superadmin and admin is only this. I'm fairly new in PHP and before to post here I found few projects like this but they a quite advanced and I can't understand them well as they are with OOP approach.

So I have made few tables in database: `users`, `action_permissions` and `user_permissions`.

Table `users` hold data for users.. nothing special:

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_username | varchar(35) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_password | char(64)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_email    | varchar(55) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_role     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `action_permission` hold gp_name: Creat(1), Read(2), Update(4), Delete(8)

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| gpid          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| gp_name       | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| gp_permission | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `user_permissions` hold `role_id.user_permissions = users.user_role`. In permission_namespace I store SuperAdmin or Admin..and permission_action is gp_permission

```
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| permission_id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| role_id              | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| permission_namespace | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| permission_action    | int(4)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So far so good. I have successfully logged in with superadmin and admin and I use this query to see if I get proper `permission_action`:

```
$value = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *
                            FROM users
                            LEFT JOIN user_permissions ON users.user_role = user_permissions.role_id
                            WHERE user_role = ?"); 
$value->bindValue(1, $_SESSION['user_role'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$value->execute();
foreach($value as $row)
{ 
       ....
}
```

Now I have few questions:

1) Since this wont be some complex system is this approach acceptable i.e. is it correct?

2) Can you provide me with simple example when user login into system how to show stuff that only with his roles can see? Do I need multiple `if{}else{}` conditions on the page or I can have some class page and include?

Example:

user with permissions of admin login in. He then must see only CRUD for normal users.

user with permissions of superadmin log in. He will see CRUD for admins and normal users.

p.s. Sorry for long post but I'm almost done this.. just need a little help to finish it.

Comment: The approach is fine for what you want to do. As for checking the permissions, I'd recommend using a method for this, as in `if (User::isAllowedTo('post')) {...}` and so on.

Comment: Thank's for the comment. This is what I can't understand.. where to use this? Do I need to make private pages such as `superadmin.php` and `admin.php` and when they log to redirect to pages which they can see and there to check for permissions?